# Hide and Show Toolbar on touching anywhere on screen

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, toolbar, ontouchlistener

I have successfully implemented the on scroll toolbar Hide/Show but i am stuck at **onTouch Hide/Show toolbar**. i have researched many related questions but nothing works for me. I want my toolbar to **hide** when user **touches on screen** and again **shows** when the screen is **touched again**, please help

> I am using Android Studio

below is my **OnScrollListener java class**

```
this.mrecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            int mLastFirstVisibleItem = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            final int currentFirstVisibleItem = layout.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (currentFirstVisibleItem > this.mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                HomePage.this.getSupportActionBar().hide();
            } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < this.mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
                HomePage.this.getSupportActionBar().show();
            }

            this.mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
        }
    });
```

**Updated**

```
 mrecyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                if(actionBar.isShowing()) {
                    actionBar.hide();
                } else
                    actionBar.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

this code works, but the problem now is that whenever i **touch the screen** it **shows the toolbar** and when i **pick up my finger** it **hide itself**, and as i am **using RecyclerView** it is getting difficult to scroll with all that showing and hiding. please help to **make it stable** so that if i touch once it stays shown and on another touch it hides itself.

Comment: All you need to do is register **onTouchEvent** to the views in order to detect the touch.

Maintain a flag and show/hide the tool bar on the basis of the flag.

Comment: i have registered onTouchListener to RecycleView , can you please help me with the **flags**

Comment: boolean isToolbarVisible; 

//when screen is touched
if(isToolbarVisible){
hideToolbar;
isToolbarVisible=false;
}else{
showToolBar;
isToolbarVisible=true;
}

Comment: i tried, but it does not work :(

Comment: @SubhechhuKhanal i have updated my question with onTouch can you please edit it and tell me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go. This should work :)

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (actionBar.isShowing()) {
                        actionBar.hide();
                    } else {
                        actionBar.show();
                    }
                    return true;
                } else return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: the upper code works fine but the only problem now is that whenever i try to  touch anywhere for some other function the toolbar again gets show and hide for example if i scroll it again get shown on one touch and hide on another scroll, can you please tell me how to overcome this.

Answer (score 0):

Use onTouchListener to your root layout. And write your code inside callback.

Comment: i have done it above but nothing works, it shows my toolbar and when i put finger on my screen it hides it and after picking finger it again shows it, it does not wait for second touch

Comment: For the first touch set boolean flag. And handle scenario according to your condition. Or you can handle it using touch counter.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i am unable to implement boolean flag can you please help me out here